# Changing exported PDF style jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, git, actionscript-3, flash, pdf

I am using [Table Tools](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/) extension of DataTables version 1.10.0. to export pdf I have written the following codes:

```
            var tb = p('#rptTable');
            tb.DataTable({
            dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "../../../js/DataTable/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf", /// <reference path="../../../js/DataTable/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" />

        "aButtons": [
            "copy",
            "csv",
            "xls",
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                "sPdfMessage": "Attendance Report"     
            },
            "print"
        ]
```

The excel and pdfs are exporting successfully. But, in pdf the font size is a bit large

I've googled and found that I have to edit ZeroClipboardPdf.as Alas! there is no ZeroClipboardPdf.as file inside the downloaded File. Then i found a script of the same named at [Git](https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/blob/master/as3/ZeroClipboardPdf.as#L1). I don't know how to code in actionscript. I've changed the pdf.setFont() area. Then built ZeroClipboardPdf.swf. Then i renamed it as copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf. Now this file is not exporting any of these formats.